# Running Background Service in iOS

Tags: ios, service, push-notification, intervals, alarm

I am a new bee in iOS apps development. I want to create a background service in iOS. I also want to mention a particular time of the day and interval (every 2 hours) to call the service (kind of an Alarm to invoke service). When the service runs, some task should get performed independent of the state of app i.e. app can be in active or inactive state. Any example of it or a code snippet of implementation will help me implement this functionality.

Comment: learn about localNotification in apple docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Code

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

[Timer invalidate];
    Timer = nil;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Background process is Start(EnterBackground)!");
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask ;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120.0f target:self  selector:@selector(process)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the Timer here? It is giving error in the code.

Comment: In .h file declare NSTimer *Timer;

Comment: Thank you so much. This works !!
But is this the correct way to run something in background? Is there anything like services in iOS?

Comment: And is it possible to mention some particular time, for example at 11:00 am ?